# unable to download maven repositories due to custom settings.xml?

Tags: maven, maven-3

Here is my situation:

I am able to run `mvn install` on my personal computer and the build successful.

But when I run the same at workstation, I get the following error. This is most likely because I have a `settings.xml` in `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml` which refers to my company's repo and DOES NOT allow to fetch from remote maven repo. How can I overcome this behavior?

Both my workstation and personal computer runs mac OS X.

Here is the `settings.xml`(I have replaced real names with dummy ones)

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dummy</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <dummy-groupId>com.mycompany.mydummy</dummy-groupId>
                <dummy-name>my-java-ee-app</dummy-name>
                <dummy-Mode>FALSE</dummy-Mode>
            </properties>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>mycompany Release Repository</id>
                    <name>central maven release repository</name>
                    <url>
                        http://maven1.mycompany.com:8080/myartifactories/repo
                    </url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>mycompany Snapshot Repository</id>
                    <name>central maven snapshot repository</name>
                    <url>
                        http://maven1.mycompany.com:8080/myartifactories/repo
                    </url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>mycompany Release Plugin Repository</id>
                    <name>central maven release repository</name>
                    <url>
                        http://maven1.mycompany.com:8080/myartifactories/repo
                    </url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>mycompany Snapshot Plugin Repository</id>
                    <name>maven snapshot repository</name>
                    <url>
                        http://maven1.mycompany.com:8080/myartifactories/repo
                    </url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
```

**Error**:

`Could not resolve dependencies for project org.glassfish.javaeetutorial:roster-ejb:ejb:7.0.5: Failure to find org.glassfish.javaeetutorial:roster-common:jar:7.0.5 in http://maven1.mycompany.com:8080/myartifactories/repo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of mycompany Release Repository has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]`

**EDIT**:

I DO see the central repo in my effective pom:
Here is the condensed version of it

```
<repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
```

Comment: are you referring to some dependencies in pom.xml which are only available in your company hosted repository ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi: no I am not. I suspect it is not going to maven remote to fetch the dependency..

Comment: try adding other repository in your pom.xml under that profile that explicitly points to central repository at url `http://central.maven.org/maven2/`

Comment: @JigarJoshi: seems my effective pom has `<url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>`

Comment: did you run effective pom on that profile ?

Comment: I did on eclipse, since effective pom is merging default with overridden, I thought `central repo` must be included..

Comment: try running it on `mvn help:effective-pom -Pdummy` and lets make sure if it has central repository listed

Comment: @JigarJoshi: I see the central repo when running effective-pom. please see the edit above

Comment: note: maven tried to fetch a jar roster-common:jar:7.0.5 but it could not be found. so maven put a placeholder in the local repo. now, if you have changed the settings.xml of that machine, and added for example another repo where this jar resides, maven will not search for it again (till you force it to, or till an interval elapses). running mvn -U is not that good since it will update ALL repo! better way is to DELETE this placeholder from the local repo.

Comment: @OhadR: what you want me to delete? please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is to configure a repository manager on your mac and configure the different repositories in the repository manager. Or you can use git to switch your `${HOME}/.m2/settings.xml` to different state.

**Update:**

1. Create a git repository in ${HOME}/.m2/ via `git init` there
   add an appropriate `.gitignore` file which contains a single line
   `repository`. Checkin your `settings.xml` file. Create a branch
   for example `git co -b company` make the appropriate changes for 
   your company and check in that state. Afterwards you can simply
   switch by changing into the appropriate branch in git.
2. Setup Repository manager like Nexus (on your machine)
   and configure there necessary repositories you need. If you working
   on company site you can activate/deactivate the appropriate repository
   via the UI of Nexus which means you have no change in your
   `settings.xml`.

My preference is the local git repository which make life easier for me as well.

Comment: more elaborate explanation on the two methods will be very helpful. or if you can point to resources that explain how to set this up, it will be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems your repo is cached locally and needs to be updated forcefully.
Try following to force the updates:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

Comment: well, if it does not find a dependency in local repo, it must seek from remote by default

Answer (score 0):

I see in your error you have pasted:

> "...was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be
>   reattempted until the update interval of mycompany".

so you want to delete this cache, i.e. to delete it from the local repo. Go to your local repo (usually .m2/...) and delete the "placeholder": go to directory org/glassfish/javaeetutorial/7.0.5 and there you should see roster-common.XXX cached - delete it.

If this keep happening, after you deleted the 'cached' from the repo, it means that maven cannot find it in any repo. So you have to re-check your repositories definitions. For example, **why don't you have the "central" repo defined in your settings.xml (like all other repos)**?